# How to always disable/skip a job in Github actions? (Not step/action)

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have the following workflow:

```yaml
name: CICD

# ...

jobs:
  CI:
    uses: ...
  CD:
    needs: [CI]
    uses: ...
```

I have encountered an issue that needs me to temporally disable the CD job that uses other workflows (not just a single step or action).

##### What I have tried:

There seems to be a recent update about ["Skipping workflow runs"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs)

> You can skip workflow runs triggered by the push and pull_request events by including a command in your commit message.

This sounds inconvenient, at the bottom they mention:

> You can also disable a workflow from running. For more information, see ["Disabling and enabling a workflow."](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow)

In which you can disable and re-enable a workflow using the GitHub UI, the REST API, or GitHub CLI. However, this doesn't seem to work for when the workflow is being used as a [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

I can also simply omit the logic:

```yaml
name: CICD

# ...

jobs:
  CI:
    uses: ...
```

But I want to preserve the version control history differently (+ make my pipeline explicitly state the job was disabled / skipped)

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can use [conditions to control job execution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution):

> You can instead use the `jobs.<job_id>.if` conditional to prevent a job from running unless a condition is met.

So if you update your CD job workflow to an indefinite negative condition:

```yaml
name: CICD

# ...

jobs:
  CI:
    uses: ...
  CD:
    if: false
    needs: [CI]
    uses: ...
```

It will cause the job to always be skipped (i.e. "disabled").